# Automatic page reload with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reload

I have a test page that I keep all my labs on on my local IDE (MAMP). I recently wrote a small php script that will read the directory and create a link of each file in that directory which is help to me as now i don't have to write out the full local url each time to test a new file. I still have to refresh the page though every time i create a new file so its' read. I wanted to set the page to being 'self-reading' so that when i add something, it would appear on the page. I thought Ajax would be a good use of this but the script i tried doesn't work. I've no knowledge of ajax and or jQuery - i'm a super newb honestly - but i'm trying to grow.

My problem in a nut shell: The script does not appear to update the page (maybe it is and i'm not doing it right? I don't know - maybe i ought to be using javascript to refresh the page?)

my code:

```
<!-- For ease of use, use JQuery hosted lib- you can download any version and link to it locally also -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load("response.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('response.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<div id="responsecontainer">

<?php //index.php
$dir_open = opendir('.');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){

    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $link = "<a href='./$filename' target='_blank'> $filename </a><br />";
        echo $link;
    }
}
closedir($dir_open);
?>

</div>
<!-- End jQuery auto update div -->
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have a javascript that reloads the page, doing what i want. But part of attempting to use ajax is that I want to try something with ajax - this might not be the right thing to do with ajax, i don't know, as i said i'm pretty green. it seemed like it migh be a viable idea to do with ajax though maybe? Yes? No?

Comment: At first glance, `$.ajaxSetup()` settings appears to be called after at lease 2 `$.ajax()` (`.load()`) requests. `$.ajaxSetup()`, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/. Also, `.load()` may be expecting `html` at response. Does the php pieces work to populate `responsecontainer` ?

Comment: The php works fine, and i was very happy with myself for getting that to work on my own. So i thought maybe it was time to try tipping my toe into ajax. But i think i see my error in that i stated 'response.php' instead of 'indexReload.php' which is what i named the file. Once i changed 'response.php' to 'index.php' it works